# PBFT view-change: What happens to committed operations after the valid snapshot?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, blockchain, distributed-system

PBFT says that if the timer of backup i expires in view v then it starts a view change for v+1 by multicasting `<view-change, v+1, n, C, P, i>` where n is the sequence number of the last stable checkpoint s and P is a set containing a set Pm for each request m that prepared at i with a sequence number higher than n.

Now, the checkpoints are taken periodically so, there can be prepared messages at i with a sequence number higher than n which are already committed. We don't want these to be included in Pm as they are already committed.
So, how does PBFT handles that?

Comment: UPDATE: The answer is mentioned in safety section of the paper. Suppose k has a message m which is committed locally with sequence number n. The algorithm redoes the three phases of the atomic multicast protocol for the m with the same sequence number n and the the new view number, unless the new-view message contains a view-change message with a stable checkpoint with a sequence number higher than n.

Answer (score 1):

I think that those messages are executed again. When a *view-change* happens, all the nodes would be in the same checkpoint.

When the *"new" primary* for the view `v + 1` receives `2⨍` valid *view-change messages*, multicasts a *new-view message*. In the message that is sent, it indicates:

- V: set of received and valid *view-change messages*.
- P: set of *pre-prepared unprocessed messages*. These messages are calculate  as follows:

  - From the last stable checkpoint, you get the sequence number of the last executed request. This value will correspond to the `min-s`.
  - Take the largest sequence number of all *prepared messages* you have received. This value will correspond to the `max-s`.
  - As a result, it generates as many pre-prepared messages as needed.

Each node saves the log of the messages that are not inside a chekcpoint, so they don't need to be procesed again.

Comment: If the messages which were committed and are not in the checkpoint then if they are executed again during a view-change, won't it change the state of the node? Why would we want to generate pre-prepared messages for them again and do a check in the log to see if they have been executed and are not part of the checkpoint?

Comment: The state of the node is set to the state stablished at the checkpoint, so the execution won't not change in a different way the state of the node. On the other hand, we don't check the log to see if the messages have been executed, but to don't have to execute them again we reload the result of the previous execution.